# Return an anonymous class from factory function

Tags: php, class, anonymous, anonymous-class

I am trying to instantiate an [anonymous class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) via a factory function.
Unfortunately for me, the function returns the exact same class for each call, which is getting me in trouble while using static variables.
It has been said in PHP documentation that:

> All objects created by the same anonymous class declaration are instances of that very class.

Menas that the following code:

```
function anonymous_class() {
    return new class {};
}

if (get_class(anonymous_class()) === get_class(anonymous_class()))
    echo 'same class';
```

Will always refer to the same class. I wonder if there is any way to create a brand new class from the same function.

Then I will be able to accomplish the following work flow with the expected outputs like the bottom manual example.

```
function factory(string $param) {
    return new class($param) {
        public string $param;
        public static Closure $getter;

        public function __construct(string $param) {
            $this->param = $param;

            static::$getter = function () {
                return $this->param;
            };
        }

        public static function getStaticVar(): string
        {
            $getter = static::$getter;
            return $getter();
        }
    };
}

$world = factory("Hello World");
$nurse = factory("Hello Nurse");

echo $world::getStaticVar(); //Output: Hello Nurse
echo $nurse::getStaticVar(); //Output: Hello Nurse
```

Instead of copying the class code manually, which does give the expected result:

```
$world = new class("Hello World") {
    public string $param;
    public static Closure $getter;

    public function __construct(string $param) {
        $this->param = $param;
        static::$getter = function () { return $this->param; };
    }

    public static function getStaticVar(): string
    {
        $getter = static::$getter;
        return $getter();
    }
};

$nurse = new class("Hello Nurse") {
    public string $param;
    public static Closure $getter;

    public function __construct(string $param) {
        $this->param = $param;
        static::$getter = function () { return $this->param; };
    }

    public static function getStaticVar(): string
    {
        $getter = static::$getter;
        return $getter();
    }
};

echo $world::getStaticVar(); //Output: Hello World
echo $nurse::getStaticVar(); //Output: Hello Nurse
```

Comment: “Unfortunately for me, the function returns the exact same object” - [no it doesn’t](https://3v4l.org/UY8h6 ). Yes the classes are considered identical, the object is different. Yes, when using `static` you do interact and change the global static instance wish is shared. However, your problem isn’t exactly related to the anonymous class, that’s just the nature of static variables in classes. https://3v4l.org/8h1E4. Yes you could argue that every instance of an anonymous class should be unique but you’d need to create an [RFC](https://news-web.php.net/group.php?group=php.internals) for that

Comment: @ChrisHaas First of all, thank you for your time. Your code sample is having the same outputs as mine, maybe there was a version of a working sample before? I don't see much changes in there but changing the dynamic created class to a fixed one, which is not what I'm needing. Yes, my problem might be related to the nature of static variables. However, this nature does its thing when I just avoid the factory method. Is it even possible to solve this? Or creating RFC (which I'm gonna do, thanks) is my last way? I was thinking about eval function to get it working but I prefer to avoid it.

Comment: The first link shows that the _classes_ are the same but the _objects_ are different. It might sound like semantics, but it is a very important difference. I cannot fathom of a reason for wanting to create instance variables of a class but then wanting to call static methods on them. No judgment, I believe you’ve got a reason, I just can’t think of one. The second link just shows that the situation isn’t isolated to just anonymous classes, that is the design of static class properties. Lastly, although more code than the factory, you could explore traits: https://3v4l.org/JFJsY